# Create a new keymap in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, keymapping

I use the default keymap `Ctrl+Shift+Period` to insert `<%= %>` quite often. Such a small shortcut sped up the way I edit my views. Now I want to add a new keymap that allows me to add `<% %>` when say `Ctrl+Shift+Comma` is pressed.

I checked out the [JetBrains "Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts" DOC](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) and could only find a way how to edit the default keymaps.

Does anyone have a method for creating a new keymap?

Note: I'm currently running RubyMine 6.3.3

Comment: Are you looking to create an actual keymap or a new quick-key? They're two different things in RubyMine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use the default keymap Ctrl+Shift+Period

You are using wrong terms.

What you called a "keymap" is actually a "shortcut" (keyboard or mouse one).

Keymap in terms of IDE is a collection of shortcuts that associated with specific actions.

---

You cannot create **brand new and empty keymap** -- there is no real reason/benefit doing that for **ordinary** user (although it makes sense when creating keymap of another product) as all actions will have no shortcuts at all.

Your only option is to **make a copy of any** (most suitable for you) **bundled keymap and then alter it as you wish**. This way you will have all shortcuts from original keymap (unless overridden) plus your changes on a top. Therefore the link you have found is valid.

This way, if devs will add new action with some shortcut in next version, it will also be available in your keymap as your one inherits the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this sort of thing, because you can change it on the fly. Default is globally active hotkeys, although with a little tweaking to your AHK script a la `IfWinActive[,RubyMine]` you can make your hotkeys, or a subset of them, apply only to RubyMine.